# Mocking Application Variants in Unit Test for Custom Gradle Plugin That Depends On Android Plugin

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing a Gradle plugin.  My plugin depends on the Android Gradle plugin.  My plugin adds a task for every Android Application Variant.  Each task name is built from the variant name.

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.android.applicationVariants.all {
            project.task(type: SendApkTask, dependsOn: it.assemble, "send${it.name.capitalize()}Apk")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a unit test for MyPlugin#apply(Project).  The test should verify that the task was added.  By default there should just be release and debug variants.

```
public class MyPluginTest {

    Project project

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyPluginAddsTasks() {
        project.apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        project.apply plugin: MyPlugin

        assertNotNull(project.tasks['sendReleaseApk'])
    }
}
```

I can not get this assertion to pass.  After debugging I found that `project.applicationVariants` is empty.  My closure that adds tasks is never running. How do I get the Android Gradle Plugin mocked effectively for my test?  Do I need to setup a whole mock file directory with `ProjectBuilder`?

Comment: Try calling `project.evaluate()` before your assertions. It's very possible that the android plugin is doing configuration in a `project.afterEvaluate {...}` block, as is common in plugins that do configuration time work that depends on things like custom project extensions.

Comment: Thanks! If you post an answer I will accept it instead of my own.  This definitely set me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When unit testing plugins using `ProjectBuilder` it's typically necessary to explicitly call `Project.evaluate()` in cases where plugins utilize `Project.afterEvaluate()`. Add the following just before you assertions.

```
project.evaluate()
```

The Android Gradle Plugin also requires `project.android` to to be setup or a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

```
project.android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
}
```